# On documents found over the internet and sites that make them available

Tags: discussion, copyright, specific-answer

Yesterday on MO I saw [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457474/finding-lectures-pdf-four-lectures-on-simple-groups-and-singularities) and gave [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/457474/finding-lectures-pdf-four-lectures-on-simple-groups-and-singularities/457547#457547) by posting a link I found by googling (more precisely, I used DuckDuckGo). The sought for paper is from a series of preprints issued by the University of Groningen (Rijksuniversiteit Groningen), therefore I thought it was something not under a paywall, wrote a simple disclaimer and posted it.
 Nevertheless, I noted that the link is offered by the [Anna's Archive](https://en.annas-archive.org/) which seems a meta search engine which give results from Sci-Hub, Library Genesis and other sites which, in some known cases, are able to circumvent paywalls. Thus here's the **question**: even if the said paper is freely distributable (as possibly may be many items found by using the same tool), should I delete my answer since it gives a link to a web site with potentially paywall-break capacities?

**Note**. I search here on meta for questions on the or analogous same topic, but I just found the following four, which are only loosely related

- [Does MathOverflow help people get past paywalls?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4284/does-mathoverflow-help-people-get-past-paywalls)
- [Are Links to Articles Behind a Paywall Acceptable Answers?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3875/are-links-to-articles-behind-a-paywall-acceptable-answers/3877)
- [edits with links to material under restricted access](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3193/edits-with-links-to-material-under-restricted-access/3195)
- [Are Links to Articles Behind a Paywall Acceptable Answers?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3875/are-links-to-articles-behind-a-paywall-acceptable-answers/3876)

**Edit**. Thanks to a [suggestion by Martin Sleziak](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243?m=64663826#64663826), I got aware of another relevant Q&A, precisely the following one:

- [What to do when a post contains a "suspicious" link (possibly with copyrighted material)?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3953/what-to-do-when-a-post-contains-a-suspicious-link-possibly-with-copyrighted-m)

Comment: And now that you included the link *here*, you cannot even post links to meta.mathoverflow.net in answers any longer, as someone might use them to get to illegally distributed content if they click enough. (In other words, the idea that links become tainted transitively by association is absurd.)

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks. Now I see that his way of proceed may soon result in a recursive prohibition issue nightmare.